# Website is running on firefox but getting blur on chrome

Tags: java, php, html, css

Hello I am working on a website that is running properly on firefox browser but when I try it on chrome it is getting blur automatically when slider run to next slide.

Web Link: http://www.kaberaglobal.com/

Answer (score 0):

problem is height for `slider-banner-container`

chrome getting `height :23555px` something & Firefox getting `height:576px;`

Comment: the slider runs fine for first slide the height of the slider is perfect but when it changes the slide haight automatically got changed. Is there any way to fix that,

Comment: add .slider-banner-container{height:100% !important;}